# Passing Flash to redirect_to with Indifferent Access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to set flash variables within a `redirect_to` but having problems.

When I use this, the hash gets passed through, but there is no indifferent access. (ie: I can use `'key'` but not `:key`)

```
redirect_to root_url, :flash=>params.merge({:error=>'no-results'}.with_indifferent_access)
```

It's also possible I'm approaching this completely wrong.  It's a search form requesting a different action, that redirects back to the search form (on `root_url`) if there are no results.  I'm passing `params` back so I can set the form fields back to what the user selected.

Thanks!

Edit: the example I had previously posted as "working fine" did not actually work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a non-standard use of the flash... which is meant for storing a message to be displayed to the user.
It also seems a bit roundabout way of doing what you really need - which I'm assuming is just a quick place to stash the params while you redirect yes?

Have you considered just using the session directly?

eg:

```
session[:saved_params] = params.merge :error=>'no-results'
```

then in the new action:

```
real_params = session[:saved_params]
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to look up with indifferent access? The way you have it now the argument to `merge` is what gets converted.  Perhaps you are looking for

```
redirect_to root_url, :flash=>params.merge({:error=>'no-results'}).with_indifferent_access
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `root :to` in your route is redirecting to another page like `root :to => redirect('[PAGE]')`.

This happened to me and I had to use the resource path to redirect